# How can I find percentage of variables from between each other

Tags: percentage

I have a big data from my project. I try to figure out the percentage from between each other. However, I could not find any result my data. For example, I have a cherry data, I have to find percentage of color as sugar on my data. I want to find the sugar ratio of color.

Comment: What is the format of the data? Adding en example of the data format and any code you have written so far will help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you didn't specify any technology, so I'll keep this generic.

There are several ways to do this. This is one way:

1. Add up all the values of your collection to get the total
2. For each item (or group) divide the value by that total to get the ratio, and multiply by 100 to get the percentage.